# Do all Github repos always require both username and email?

Tags: git, github

When trying to commit to a Github repo, I received the following error:

```
fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed.  Run 
git config --global user.email "you@example.com" 
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

I know what this error is and how to fix it.

My question is, do all Github repos always require both username and email?  Or is this requirement a configurable option?  If it is configurable, how can I change the requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with **GitHub**. It's `git` requirements.

You can read [Getting Started - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

> The first thing you should do when you install Git is to set your user name and email address. This is important because every Git commit uses this information, and it’s immutably baked into the commits you start creating.

As it said, your user name and email address will be baked into your commits(baked into SHA1, you can refer to [The anatomy of a Git commit](https://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html) if you want learn about it internally). So you must set your user name and email address before using `git`.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I just tried this in a new local repo with no remote, and it still required user/email.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Git uses a username to associate commits with an identity. The Git username is not the same as your GitHub username.

You can change the name that is associated with your Git commits using the git config command. The new name you set will be visible in any future commits you push to GitHub from the command line. If you'd like to keep your real name private, you can use any text as your Git username.

Changing the name associated with your Git commits using git config will only affect future commits and will not change the name used for past commits.

Setting your Git username for every repository on your computer
Open the terminal.

Set a Git username:

$ git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"
Confirm that you have set the Git username correctly:

$ git config --global user.name

> Mona Lisa
>   Setting your Git username for a single repository
>   Open the terminal.

Change the current working directory to the local repository where you want to configure the name that is associated with your Git commits.

Set a Git username:

$ git config user.name "Mona Lisa"
Confirm that you have set the Git username correctly:

$ git config user.name

> Mona Lisa